# Can't get counter variable in event handler

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag-and-drop, kineticjs

```
k=0;
var sf = new Array();
function draw_sf (type,sf_text,schriftgroesse,sf_width,sf_height,x0,y0,ports_top,ports_right,ports_bottom,ports_left) {
    sf[k] = new Kinetic.Group({
        draggable: true
    });

    sf[k]['x0']=x0;
    sf[k]['y0']=y0;

    m=0;
    sf[k][m] = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: x0,
        y: y0,
        width: sf_width,
        height: sf_height,
        fill: '#EEE',
        stroke: '#000',
        strokeWidth: randbreite_sf
    });
    sf[k].add(sf[k][m]);
    m++;


    sf[k].on('dragend', function() {
        var dx=parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("dx")[0].value);
        var dy=parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("dy")[0].value);
        sf[k]['x']=sf[k]['x0']+dx;
        sf[k]['y']=sf[k]['y0']+dy;
    });
    boxLayer.add(sf[k]);
    k++;
}
```

My function draw_sf() draws rectangles, which can be moved my drag&drop. After being droped (event handler 'dragend') i want to save the new position of the element in an array. But my counter variable 'k' doesnt count in the dragend-function. k is always the number of times i called the draw_sf(). 
So how can i save the actual positions of my rectangles?

Comment: At a quick glance, try adding var before you declare k.  I'm not sure what browser youre using, but I recall javascript treating it like a new variable if you dont declare it in an older version of FF, not sure these days as I always declare.

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the approach a bit into something like:

```
var sf = new Array();
function draw_sf(type, sf_text, schriftgroesse, sf_width, sf_height, x0, y0, ports_top, ports_right, ports_bottom, ports_left) {
  var kineticGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
    draggable:true
  });

  kineticGroup['x0'] = x0;
  kineticGroup['y0'] = y0;

  m = 0;
  kineticGroup[m] = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x:x0,
    y:y0,
    width:sf_width,
    height:sf_height,
    fill:'#EEE',
    stroke:'#000',
    strokeWidth:randbreite_sf
  });
  kineticGroup.add(kineticGroup[m]);
  m++;


  kineticGroup.on('dragend', function () {
    var dx = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("dx")[0].value);
    var dy = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("dy")[0].value);
    kineticGroup['x'] = kineticGroup['x0'] + dx;
    kineticGroup['y'] = kineticGroup['y0'] + dy;
  });
  boxLayer.add(kineticGroup);
  sf.push(kineticGroup);
}
```

The truth is that you actually don't need any counter to store the history of the rect positions - you can just push it to the array using Array.prototype.push: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp